# How to set a variable as a resource in dataweave component?

Tags: mule, esb, dataweave

My DataWeave configuration is as below.

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="5b272b5c-4f37-4e09-8608-756169041833" doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload resource="file:D:/Disc/sample.dwl"></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

I am trying to externalize the transformation logic from the above.

My question is: Instead of using the file path directly in the RESOURCE attribute  can I use a variable which has the file path in it? If yes, how do I achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Not possible in Mule 3.8.5. The normal way like `<dw:set-payload resource="#[flowVars.file]">` and also the spring properties way `<dw:set-payload resource="${file}">` won't work. By the way, the mapping should be always part of the application and the full QA. Therefore it is okay that it can not be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Use properties, with properties you can replace this value and store them in an external file:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-properties

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How do i call the property value into the RESOURCE attribute?